# Can only one particle exist at a defined point in spacetime?

Tags: particle-physics, spacetime, superposition

And for the contrasting question, may two or more particles be superimposed at the same point in spacetime?

Comment: Please don't make radical changes to questions that invalidate existing answers. Instead ask a new question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A particle isn't located at a point. Particles are always delocalised over a non-zero volume of space, so while the expectation value of a particle's position is a point, the particle is not located at that point.

For a particle to be located at a point its wavefunction would have to be an eigenfunction of the [position operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_operator), i.e. a Dirac delta, but these functions are not well defined. For example they have an infinite uncertainty in momentum.

So the question would be better phrased as whether two particles can have wavefunctions that completely overlap, and the answer is that yes they can. The only restriction comes from the [exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle), which tells us that two fermions cannot occupy the same quantum state, but two particles can overlap without being in the same state. For example two particles travelling at right angles to each other could completely overlap.

Comment: For an extreme example of this, there are some theories of dark matter that rely on axion clouds that would gather around black holes, in a situation where $10^{77}$ particles would be in the same state! Source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03958.pdf

Comment: I changed the framing of the question more in terms of general relativity. I'm not quite up to quantum mechanics yet.

Comment: @john-rennie Though your answer makes sense, since even if the wavefunctions of two particles overlap, it does not necessarily mean they will be at the same location when observed.

Comment: @Theoretically_cat I'm not sure if there's any "popular science" explanation of how particles are "localized" when they interact that most physicists would agree with. With my limited understanding, I think that depends on your interpretation of what the wave function and particle interactions mean. The solution of the wave equation (for the two particles) gives you an answer that doesn't really have this separate "newtonian" location. Just like the sound wave that you're hearing doesn't have a definite location in time or space, despite causing a very definite "sound feeling" in your brain.

Comment: `two fermions cannot occupy the same quantum state`...but two bosons *can* occupy the same quantum state.  Depends on what OP means by "particle" (or "superimposed at the same point", for that matter).  The classic experiment to reference here is probably the formation of a [Bose-Einstein Condensate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate)

Answer (score -2):

If we consider the wavefunction of your particle the particle is at every instant at a definite point in spacetime. This point though is constantly changing randomly (unpredictable) within the confines of the wavefunction and this random changing is "concentrated" there where the absolute value of the squared wavefunction (which gives the probability of finding the particle) has the highest value(s). When we make a position measurement we measure a range around the position (a precise measurement is impossible) where the particle finds itself at the time of the measurement. This is not the standard Copenhagen interpretation which states that the **act** of the measurement determines the (range of) position(s), without the particle having a definite position **before** the measurement. But it's a valid interpretation. God **does** throw a dice (as you probably know, Einstein said that god does not play dice), but already **before** the measurement.

The same holds for two particles (let's say they are identical bosons to avoid the exclusion principle) whose wavefunctions find themselves in a superposition. The particles always find themselves at a definite point in spacetime but are randomly changing in accordance with the wavefunction. I think it's clear that the two particles will never find themselves at the same point in spacetime.